# Smoother curves

Tags: pgfplots

With the attached code I have the result in picture. In the range `0-20` it is very clear that the curve has sharp changes and this is not aesthetically good.

Is there a way to make curves smoother? Thanks

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth, height=10cm,
    xlabel=$Pressure~(m~water)$,
    ylabel={$Water~content~(v/v)$},
    legend style={draw=none, legend columns=2, at={(.9,.9)}}]
    \addplot+[blue,no marks,domain=0.001:160] {.508-1.52398*exp(-(13702.2/x)^0.13266)};
    \addplot+[violet,no marks,domain=0.001:160] {.445-0.34900*exp(-(30.0706/x)^0.23650)};
    \addplot+[red,no marks,domain=0.001:160] {.503-0.41288*exp(-(1.56530/x)^0.66572)};
    \addplot+[orange,no marks,domain=0.001:160] {.465-0.39848*exp(-(0.67406/x)^0.84737)};
    \addplot+[green,no marks,domain=0.001:160] {.350-0.31765*exp(-(0.53648/x)^1.21892)};
    \addplot+[brown,no marks,domain=0.001:160] {.395-0.38594*exp(-(0.07439/x)^0.92067)};
    \legend{Silty clay, Clay loam, Loam, Sandy loam, Medium fine loam, Coarsesand};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: add option˛`smooth` to the `\addplot` macro: `\addplot+[green,no marks,domain=0.001:160,smooth] {...}`

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but the words "Pressure", "water", and "water content" in the labels should not be inside math mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the option `smooth` makes  the curve smoother, it also results in off shooting at the edges thereby making the graph inaccurate. It is better to use `samples` key and increase the number of samples. More the samples, more finer is the curve. Here only the limiting factor is the time taken for compilation and the memory. Below is an example with `samples=500`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\textwidth, height=10cm,
        xlabel=$Pressure~(m~water)$,
        ylabel={$Water~content~(v/v)$},
        legend style={draw=none, legend columns=2, at={(.9,.9)}}]
        \addplot+[blue,no marks,domain=0.001:160,samples=500] {.508-1.52398*exp(-(13702.2/x)^0.13266)};
        \addplot+[violet,no marks,domain=0.001:160,samples=500] {.445-0.34900*exp(-(30.0706/x)^0.23650)};
        \addplot+[red,no marks,domain=0.001:160,samples=500] {.503-0.41288*exp(-(1.56530/x)^0.66572)};
        \addplot+[orange,no marks,domain=0.001:160,samples=500] {.465-0.39848*exp(-(0.67406/x)^0.84737)};
        \addplot+[green,no marks,domain=0.001:160,samples=500] {.350-0.31765*exp(-(0.53648/x)^1.21892)};
        \addplot+[brown,no marks,domain=0.001:160,samples=500] {.395-0.38594*exp(-(0.07439/x)^0.92067)};
        \legend{Silty clay, Clay loam, Loam, Sandy loam, Medium fine loam, Coarsesand};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To reduce memory usage and computation time an option is to avoid a large number of points when they are not useful (in this case for large values of `x`). To do that you can use also the key `samples at`, paired with the `...` syntax of `\foreach`; for example using `samples at={0.001,0.2,...,1,1.5,2,...,6,8,10,...,20,25,30,...,160}`.